# HTML 5 video does not play on Internet Explorer 10 & Safari

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, safari, html5-video

I have a video added on a webpage that I have working in everything except IE 10 and Safari 5.1.7. I also went through other solutions over the community, but none of them seemed to be working for me. Also tried adding IE compatible meta tag and video format fallback, but no success.
Below is the HTML I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
</head>

<body>
    <video width="400" controls>
         <source src="video/demo-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         <source src="video/demo-video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
         <source src="video/demo-video.webm" type="video/webm">
         Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Safari 5.1.7 is hopelessly ancient, don't use it for testing against modern Safari support.

Comment: Also, check the console for errors. Failing that, try known working videos. This is impossible for us to debug as-is.

Comment: console does not have any errors..

Comment: Did you try a full path to video `src="http://www.example.com/video/demo-video.mp4"` etc? Does **[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video)** play the video okay in IE 10? Now test that shown code with a direct full path to your video. If it doesn't work now then maybe your video settings are the issue. Is it MP4 video file? Can you provide a link of trimmed few seconds version to test? PS: That video link worked in IE 11 (no IE10) and I can't comment about Safari since I don't use it.

Comment: Yes..tried by giving the full path to video file..but no luck.And the above given w3schools also does not work in IE 10..However I tried to convert the video to .swf file nd it worked on IE10..However the video does play on IE11 and Egde browser..